# На какие источники нужно ссылаться при ответе?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Мне кажется, что  для этого подходят только официальные источники: Правила 1956 года в изложении Розенталя или Полный академический справочник под ред. Лопатина. В Сети много сайтов, посвященных русскому языку, они могут быть полезными, но это самодеятельное творчество.

Вот пример из последнего вопроса о постановке запятой в СПП с придаточными изъяснительными. На сайте, указанном в ссылке , сказано: "В конце предложения с косвенным вопросом НЕ СТАВИТСЯ  вопросительный знак". [Сложноподчиненные предложения с придаточными изъяснительными | videotutor-rusyaz.ru](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/295-slo)

Но эта тема в полном объёме разбирается у Розенталя, и там сказано, в каких случаях вопросительный знак можно поставить: [XX. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В КОНЦЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ И ПРИ ПЕРЕРЫВЕ РЕЧИ | evartist.narod.ru](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/41.htm)

Если придаточное предложение образует косвенный вопрос, то в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится, например: Не знаю, сколько времени я пробыл в этом положении (Л Толстой); Ты не сказала нам, почему не ходишь в училище (Федин). Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом ВСТРЕЧАЕТСЯ, если последний содержит сильно выраженную ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНУЮ интонацию, например: Не понимаю, что тебе нужно? (Чехов); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (Горький).

Наверное, будет правильнее, если давать ссылку на официальный источник, а не на пересказ.

Comment: На этом сайте часто бывают ошибки. Так что лучше сверять информацию на этом сайте с авторитетными источниками. Кстати, не могли бы вы указать пример, о котором вы говорите? Я не смог найти.

Comment: Есть еще сайт Института русского языка, там тоже есть много полезного. На этот сайт тоже можно ссылаться.

Comment: Пример в разделе:  Сложноподчинёнными предложениями с придаточными изъяснительными передаётся косвенная речь.

Comment: Да, увидел. Но это не ошибка. Просто там опущены подробности. Но можно написать им.

Comment: А мне кажется, что ошибка. Надо было тогда написать "обычно". Очень удобное слово, а то на каждое правило обязательно хотя бы одно исключение, но найдется.

Comment: Вопросы, касающиеся работы сообщества следует задавать на Мете https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Можно ссылаться на любые источники или не ссылаться вообще, если вы считаете, что вашего авторитета достаточно. Естественно ответы со ссылками на авторитетные источники смотрятся выигрышнее отсебятины и как правило получают больше баллов, но это не означает, что мнение без ссылок неверно. Ссылки нужны главным образом  для того, чтобы читатель мог понять насколько вы разбираетесь в вопросе.

Comment: Сам человек  может считать себя очень авторитетным, он даже может иметь высокий рейтинг, но в русском языке много тем, и трудно одинаково хорошо разбираться во всём.( К тому же рейтинг отвечающих зависит от времени работы). А сюда люди часто обращаются впервые, и им сложно оценить авторитет незнакомого человека, который дает им ответ. Поэтому мне кажется, что ссылка на Розенталя или  примеры из классики увеличивают значимость ответов.

Comment: @Arina поэтому опытные пользователи, чаще всего дают ссылку на источник информации. Но вопросы бывают разные, поэтому ссылка на источник лишь рекомендация, а не правило.

Comment: Ссылки нужны еще и для того (а может быть и в первую очередь для того), чтобы задавший вопрос мог самостоятельно углубиться в тему и узнать дополнительные подробности, не указанные в вашем ответе.